# Limitar soma de Intervalos (TimeSpan) em C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timespan

Olá, sou iniciante em C# e estou com um problema em somar durações de tempo...

Quero somar quatro variáveis de intervalo de tempo (do tipo TimeSpan) em outra variável de intervalo de tempo (que também precisa ser do tipo TimeSpan), inicialmente elas começam em zero:

```
public static TimeSpan tempoUM = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
public static TimeSpan tempoDOIS = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
public static TimeSpan tempoTRES = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
public static TimeSpan tempoQUATRO = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
```

Os valores são preenchidos ao longo do código (essa parte está funcionando legal)
A soma dessas quatro variáveis irá se chamar somaTEMPO.

```
somaTEMPO = tempoUM + tempoDOIS + tempoTRES + tempoQUATRO;
```

Só que tem um problema, as vezes as somas dos tempos dá um valor maior que 23:59:59, e entendo que esse formato que coloquei não aceita isso, inclusive, da um erro assim:

> Value 'x.xx:xx:xx' is out of range. Must be between 00:00:00.0000000 and 23:59:59.9999999.

Sendo assim, queria entender como fazer uma espécie de filtro que se caso a soma fosse maior que o limite ele limitasse em 23:59:59 e salvasse bonitinho.

Não sei como desenvolver, mas suponho que tenha que fazer a soma em outro tipo de variável, que sirva de auxílio (por exemplo uma chamada somaTEMPOAux), aplicar uma condicional if (se maior que 23:59:59 colocar igual à 23:59:59), e dentro, salvasse na variável em questão, somaTEMPO, aplicando uma conversão para voltar a ser do tipo TimeSpan...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro vamos entender o que são cada parametro no TimeSpan(0,0,0), o 1º é a quantidade de horas, o 2º é a quantidade de minutos e o 3º é a quantidade de segundos.

Agora que já está claro isso, depende de onde você quer usar o resultado, porque por exemplo:

```
public static TimeSpan tempoUM = new TimeSpan(23, 10, 10);
public static TimeSpan tempoDOIS = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
public static TimeSpan tempoTRES = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
public static TimeSpan tempoQUATRO = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);

public static TimeSpan tempoSOMA = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
  
tempoSOMA = tempoUM + tempoDOIS + tempoTRES + tempoQUATRO;
Console.WriteLine(tempoSOMA);
```

O resultado será: **3.23:10:10**

Que significa 3 dias 23 horas, 10 minutos e 10 segundos. Se você quiser salvar em algum lugar que só aceita de 00:00:00.0000000 a 23:59:59.9999999 vai ter que tratar o resultado, então significa que a quantidade de horas do resultado for >= (maior ou igual) a 24 horas substitua por 23:59:59. No TimeSpan tem como você fazer isso, utilizado tempoSOMA.TotalHours que retorna um inteiro com a quantidade de horas totais. Então ficaria assim:

```
if (tempoSOMA.TotalHours >= horasDuracaoDoDia)
   tempoSOMA = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
```

A horasDuracaoDoDia é o valor 24.Que você pode declarar uma variável para o código ficar mais intuitivo.

```
int horasDuracaoDoDia = 24;
```

Na documentação oficial da microsoft tem vários exemplos com timespan:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-6.0.

É um bom lugar para estudar c#.

Comment: Boa, solucionou a minha dúvida, valeu!